# What is the average latitude of all points on a hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, angle, spheres

I'm looking to calculate the average angular altitude of the sun at noon for everywhere on Earth in order to create a location-agnostic example sun. To start, I would like to calculate what the average latitude is.

Latitudes on a sphere go from 0 to 90 degrees, either North or South, usually with  negative numbers representing South. If we included both hemispheres, the average would be zero, so let's only look at one hemisphere. A naïve guess would be that the average is 45 degrees, but by reasoning in my head, there is far less surface area between 45° and 90° than there is between 0° and 45°. However, I have no idea what the formula is to calculate the area of each range of latitudes. The solution would be to solve some formula to find a value X such that 0° to X° has the same area as X° to 90°.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment

Comment: The "average" is ambiguous.  Perhaps you have in mind the *mean* with respect to some probability distribution (such as the uniform distribution on a hemisphere or on the whole sphere). In any case the Sun's elevation "at noon" varies with the season also.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems that the answer is 30 degrees based on the equations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap combined with the equation for the area of a sphere. I can write up an answer if nobody else does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

The above article tells us that formula for the surface area of a spherical cap is $A = 2{\pi}r^2(1-cos\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the pole and the cap's end. In our case we are dealing with latitude, so what we want to eventually get is $90^{\circ} - \theta$.

The surface area of a sphere is $4{\pi}r^2$. We are working with a hemisphere, so we take half this to get $2{\pi}r^2$, and we want to find the point (line) in the middle where the areas are equal, which means we want half of this area, or $A = {\pi}r^2$. We can now form the equation ${\pi}r^2 = 2{\pi}r^2(1-cos\theta)$. We can divide both sides by ${\pi}r^2$ to get $1 = 2(1-cos\theta)$ then we can get $1/2 = 1-cos\theta$ then $1/2 = cos\theta$ then $acos(1/2) = \theta$ then $\theta = 60^{\circ}$.

This means that the average (mean) latitude on a sphere is $90^{\circ} -  60^{\circ}$ or $30^{\circ}$, which answers the stated question in the title. Additionally, to answer my use case, the average sun angular altitude at noon would be the same as the equinox angular altitude at noon, which is $90^{\circ} -  latitude$ or $90^{\circ} - 30^{\circ}$ or $60^{\circ}$.